# Add new ip to existing CosmosDB account via ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I halve arm template that is overwriting existing iprules of cosmosDb account, is it possible to modify arm template so it will only add new ip and not to clean already existing rules.
My template:

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2021-10-15",
        "name": "cosmosdbaccountname",
        "location": "East US",
        "properties": {
            "ipRules": {
                "ipAddressOrRange": "some ip"
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If configuring IP Firewall to an already deployed Cosmos account, ensure the `locations` array matches what is currently deployed. You cannot simultaneously modify the `locations` array and other properties.

Below example shows how the **ipRules** property is exposed in API version 2020-04-01 or later:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "name": "[variables('accountName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2020-04-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
  "properties": {
    "consistencyPolicy": "[variables('consistencyPolicy')[parameters('defaultConsistencyLevel')]]",
    "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
    "enableAutomaticFailover": "[parameters('automaticFailover')]",
    "ipRules": [
      {
        "ipAddressOrRange": "40.76.54.131"
      },
      {
        "ipAddressOrRange": "52.176.6.30"
      },
      {
        "ipAddressOrRange": "52.169.50.45"
      },
      {
        "ipAddressOrRange": "52.187.184.26"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here's the same example for any API version prior to 2020-04-01:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts",
  "name": "[variables('accountName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2019-08-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "kind": "GlobalDocumentDB",
  "properties": {
    "consistencyPolicy": "[variables('consistencyPolicy')[parameters('defaultConsistencyLevel')]]",
    "locations": "[variables('locations')]",
    "databaseAccountOfferType": "Standard",
    "enableAutomaticFailover": "[parameters('automaticFailover')]",
    "ipRangeFilter":"40.76.54.131,52.176.6.30,52.169.50.45,52.187.184.26"
  }
}
```

Refer this [configure IP to Cosmos account using ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-firewall#configure-ip-firewall-arm)

Comment: This will overwrite rules, that database account has.

Comment: No Sergey, Please check once the documentation link provided, you can add multiple new ip address ranges to existing account.

Comment: Will it overwrite iprule that was added via azure portal?

Comment: It will not override. If you have multiple private ip addresses and if you want to override, you can do using this [Azure Cosmos Private Endpoint DNS Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/private-endpoint-dns).

Comment: I tried example from docs:
"ipRules": [
     {
      "ipAddressOrRange": "40.76.54.131"
     },
     {
      "ipAddressOrRange": "52.176.6.30"
     },
     {
      "ipAddressOrRange": "52.169.50.45"
     },
     {
      "ipAddressOrRange": "52.187.184.26"
     }
    ]

then modify iprules:
"ipRules": [
     
     {
      "ipAddressOrRange": "52.187.184.27"
     }
    ]

And it was overriden.